# Sync Framework Deletes not being applied on client

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

Heres my scenario: I was concerned about the SqlCeSyncClient applying deletes, then inserts, then updates. I have cases where a row may be de-referenced from another table, and then deleted. For example, imagine this:

I have two tables; Customer, and Area, of which Customer.Area references Area.Name with a Foreign key constraint

```
insert into Area values('Australia')
insert into Customer values('customer1','Australia')
```

-- Sync happens. Client gets 2 inserts.

```
update Customer set Area = 'New Zealand' where Area = 'Australia'
delete from Area where Name = 'Australia'
```

-- Sync happens. Client gets 1 update , and 1 delete

The SqlCeClientSyncProvider tries to apply the delete *first*, which it fails to do because of referential integrity constraints on the client.

My first question is: Why on earth did the boys at Microsoft code the SyncClient to process deletes FIRST when it breaks all referential integrity rules? Shouldn't they apply deletes LAST????

My next question is: I have managed to reverse the order by inspecting the code and writing the whole ApplyChanges method myself... but even when I do that the deletes are not applied. Is there some internal thing with datasets that means you can't change the order of processing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the order from operations ( delete, update, inserts, ...), but the order you placed your synctables...

You should have synced Area table first and after Customer table.